# How to omit specific class from URL while extracting text using python

Tags: html, python-3.x

I am extracting title & contents from URL using below

```
def extract_title_text(url):
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
    text = ' '.join(map(lambda p: p.text, soup.find_all('p')))
    return soup.title.text, text

URL = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-45482461'
titletext, text = extract_title_text(URL)
```

I would like to omit the contents from span class="off-screen" while extracting the text. Can i get some pointers please to set the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution is to filter out your tags, ie:

```
text = ' '.join(p.text for p in soup.find_all('p') if not "off-screen" in p.get("class", [])
```

For a more generic solution, `soup.find_all()` (as well as `soup.find()`) can [take a function as argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function), so you can also do this:

```
def is_content_para(tag):
    return tag.name == "p" and "off-screen" not in p.get("class", [])

text = ' '.join(p.text for p in soup.find_all(is_content_para))
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It works. Could you please advise whether it is possible to set multiple filters of 'p' class while extracting the text.

Comment: @user9477848 I'm not sure what you mean by "multiple filters of 'p' class" but if you mean "excluding 'p' tags having one or more of a given set of classes", then yes obviously, you only have to adapt the above examples.